# How do I access the value of an object nested in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array;

var arr = [0:{item:"shoe"}];

How do I get the value 'shoe'?

Comment: That code will give you a syntax error. That is not how you define an array literal.

Comment: Either: `arr = {0:{item:"shoe"}}` or `arr = [{0:{item:"shoe"}}]` or `arr = [{item:"shoe"}]`

Answer (score 0):

`arr[0].item`
or
`arr[0]["item"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, because you have a syntax error in your code;

```js
    let arr = [{0:{item:"shoe"}}, {1:{item:"shoe1"}}]
    console.log(arr[0][0].item)
```